# C++ Extract function definitions from JavaScript source

Tags: c++, parsing

I wondering how to proceed with the problem. I am writing a C++ script that will read a JavaScript file. What I want to do is create a vector of maps of the JavaScript functions found within. I can get the name easy enough with regex. However, I want to also store the entire function itself as a string. For example:

```
function myfunc (a,b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

I know how to get the string "myfunc" for the function name, but I'd also want to get the entire definition from `function` until the closing `}`. The best approach I can think of is to iterate through the characters in string starting at `function` and keeping count of opening and closing brackets, storing the string positions, and then copying the substring using those positions to a new variable. But that seems like a stupid thing to do.

Edit

Here's a sketch of what I'm talking about trying:

```
std::string::size_type finalBracket (std::string::size_type start) {

    std::string startAt (parseablecode, start);
    int bracketCount = 0;
    std::string::size_type closePosition = 0;
    bool initial = false;

    for(char& c : startAt) {

        if (c == '{') {

            ++bracketCount;

            if (!initial) initial = true;

        }

        if (c == '}')
            --breakCount;


        if (initial && bracketCount == 0) {
            closePosition += start; 
            break;

        }

        ++closePosition;

    }

    return closePosition;

}
```

Comment: Trying it your own way is never stupid. I think that keeping count of opening and closing brackets is brilliant.

Comment: In general you will need a parser, but if the functions you want to extract are "tame enough" and have no syntax errors you could probably do it with a regular expression.

Comment: Regexps can't track nested parentheses.  This won't work.

Comment: ... OP edited his answer so show curly-brace counting.  If he is willing to count parentheses and curly brace nesting, he has a much better chance. He needs to watch for complications with comments, strings, regexes-in-Javascript, and escaped characters in all of those constructs. (He hasn't even discussed the possibility he might be trying to extract these function definitions from an HTML source file, which will add another layer of counting and escaping on top of this).   Generally he's probably going to discover enough complications so that a real parser is probably a better way out.

Comment: ... and then there is "eval", which can take a string assembled from several pieces, and produce a function.  The latter is provably impossible to get right in the general case.  One might get it right in many special cases, but not without a full parser, and dataflow analyses across functions to determine possible strings that might read the eval command.